# How to make datum planes on a cone in Creo?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, modeling, cad

I am trying to make this
[image: Goal]

I was able to make the base feature but I am facing problems with the secondary features. So could anyone shed some light on how to make the datum planes on cones.

I made one feature using this [image: Plane]
as was instructed from where I am learning.
However, I am unable to make the plane for the other feature.

So far I have made this [image: Model]

Thanks in advance

Comment: The images are not loading for me - can you check this?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Sorry for inconvenience. I have done that now.

Comment: You can make a plane or projected line from the top and then make a plane either tangent to plane and cone surface or tangent to cone and on line. This allows you to easily change the angle after the fact. Sorry im in a hurry i might write this as an ansver later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont actually need a datum plane, you can do it with a revolve. But yes you can do this much more easily than you think.

1. When creating a plane click on he cone surface quilt, then change the option from *Through* to *Tangent*. Yeah the GUI is a bit sleazy the option is a drop down even if it has no affordance. Bad UX designer!

   [image]
2. Then add another constraint and choose a plane or line that defines the rotation around the central axis.

   [image]
3. And finally

   [image]

Also note extrusions can define different extrusion values to both directions so no need to create the second set of planes offset (or the extra axes for that matter). Personally I would make the planes internal to the feature creation as it clutters my view and model tree less.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I found another workaround and managed to make the model. But I had to draw it with model upside down. Your method is much more suitable as the sketch environment remains normal. It would really come handy.